# What're the requirements for module id in application.xml on WebSphere?

Tags: module, websphere, ear

I have the enterprise application for WebSphere. In `application.xml` there is the line:

```
<module id="Module_1346393735403">
```

Unfortunatelly noone can me say why the module id is in such form, it was copied from somewhere. I was trying to find some details in google about what should the id look like, but without success.

So my question is, what are the requirements for module id on WebSphere? Need it to be anything that is unique inside the application.xml, or there are some special requirements for it?

This what is misleading for me is the information from the official site: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.developer.doc%2Frefs%2Frdewcbdtrbmapmod.htm

> Ensure that the display name in the module deployment descriptor is
>   the same as the module name. For example, if the name of a Web module
>   is ProjectServicesHTTPInterface, the display-name element in the
>   deployment descriptor file web.xml must also be
>   ProjectServicesHTTPInterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message itself isn't very clear. It doesn't explain, what is module name.

For WebSphere (7) **module name** is the name of war file (without .war suffix).

The `display-name` tag must be present in web.xml of war file, and must be the same as name of war (without .war).

Comment: how is `display-name` answering question about `module id`?

Answer (score 4):

The id is just an arbitrary identifier. The value `Module_1346393735403` looks like it has been generated by some IBM tool (the number is actually a timestamp in milliseconds since the UNIX epoch). It's not even mandatory unless it is referenced by some other deployment descriptor, IBM extension descriptor or binding file.

Comment: what binding file do you refer?

Comment: The WebSphere binding file for application.xml is ibm-application-bnd.xmi.